# Frictionless Request Using FBML

Tags: facebook, user-interface, fbml

Is it possible to use frictionless request using FBML?

Currently I am using FBML tags `fb:request-form`, `fb:multi-friend-selector`, `fb:request-form-submit` to select multiple friends for requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You have to use the open graph beta api to send the requests.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the specific documentation for sending "frictionless requests" using "open graph beta api"?